# How to subscribe a SAP CAP in a different region of the same global account?

Tags: multi-tenant, sap-cap

Assume following:

- A global SAP cloud account
- One or more subaccounts in region EU10
- One or more subaccounts in region US10

You deploy a SAP CAP app in US10 with `tenant-mode` mode set to `shared`.

How to handle the routs for this use case?